# Calculating units of time in excel in order to multiply

Tags: worksheet-function

I would like a formula that can multiply a unit of time, e,g if I enter 1hr and 20 min as 1.20 and multiply by10 i should have 13 hrs 20min displayed as 13.20 but what I would get currently is 11.

Answer (score 0):

Enter 1hr 20 mins as 1:20, not 1.20. That plus specifying a "Time" format for the cells in question should get you what you need - the 1.20 isn't a time value, it's a decimal number value, so Excel treats it as such.

Comment: Good fast reply, and the "enter time as 1:20" is necessary, but he can also get the format like he wants by making the cell(s) have a custom format of h.mm